# Error trying to concatenate strings with groupby in Python

Tags: python, pandas

So, I'm new to Python and I have this dataframe with company names, country information and activities description. I'm trying to group all this information by names, concatenating the countries and activities strings.

First, I did something like this:

```
df3_['Country'] = df3_.groupby(['Name', 'Activity'])['Country'].transform(lambda x: ','.join(x))

df4_ = df3_.drop_duplicates()

df4_['Activity'] = df4_.groupby(['Name', 'Country'])['Activity'].transform(lambda x: ','.join(x))
```

This way, I got a 'SettingWithCopyWarning', so I read a little bit about this error and tried copying the dataframe before applying the functions (didn't work) and using .loc (didn't work as well):

```
df3_.loc[:, 'Country'] = df3_.groupby(['Name', 'Activity'])['Country'].transform(lambda x: ','.join(x))
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Edit: I was asked to post an example of my data. The first pic is what I have, the second one is what it should look like

[image: now I have this]

[image: I would like my that to look like this]

Comment: can you provide some of your data in question and how your output should look like  ? it will be helpful for us to provide you solution.

Comment: did it :) thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to group by the Company Name and then use some aggregating functions for the other columns, like:

```
df.groupby('Company Name').agg({'Country Code':', '.join, 'Activity':', '.join})
```

You were trying it the other way around.
Note that the empty string value ('') gets ugly with this aggregation, so you could make it more difficult with an aggregation like such:

```
df.groupby('Company Name').agg({'Country Code':lambda x: ', '.join(filter(None,x)), 'Activity':', '.join})
```

Answer (score 1):

Following should work,

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Country Code': ['HK','US','SG','US','','US'],
    'Company Name': ['A','A','A','A','B','B'],
    'Activity': ['External services','Commerce','Transfer','Others','Others','External services'],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#grouping
grp = df.groupby('Company Name')

#custom function for replacing space and adding ,
def str_replace(ser):
  s = ','.join(ser.values)
  
  if s[0] == ',':
    s = s[1:]
  
  if s[len(s)-1] == ',':
    s = s[:len(s)-1]

  return s 

#using agg functions
res = grp.agg({'Country Code':str_replace,'Activity':str_replace}).reset_index()
res
```

Output:

```
Company Name    Country Code    Activity
0   A       HK,US,SG,US     External services,Commerce,Transfer,Others
1   B       US              Others,External services
```

Comment: thanks ^^ I liked the approach using a custom function

Comment: @vibebizarrinha I have updated my code as it was replacing space with comma in Activity column something like `External services` to `External,services` now the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach this time using `transform()`

```py
# group the companies and concatenate the activities 
df['Activities'] = df.groupby(['Company Name'])['Activity'] \
  .transform(lambda x : ', '.join(x))

# group the companies and concatenate the country codes
df['Country Codes'] = df.groupby(['Company Name'])['Country Code'] \
  .transform(lambda x : ', '.join([i for i in x if i != '']))
# the list comprehension deals with missing country codes (that have the value '')


# take this, drop the original columns and remove all the duplicates
result = df.drop(['Activity', 'Country Code'], axis=1) \
  .drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
# reset index isn't really necessary
```

Result is

```
  Company Name                                      Activitys   Country Codes
0            A  External services, Commerce, Transfer, Others  HK, US, SG, US
1            B                      Others, External services              US
```